# "Add to cart" form doesn't add products to the cart

Tags: 7, views, commerce, caching

I have an e-commerce site. In that, I have created product listing page using views. I have added the *Add to cart* field in the view, so every product in the view will have it. I have enabled view caching.

When I click on that button for the first time, it adds the product to cart. After that, the product isn't added to the cart; it just reloads the page and it doesn't throw any error.

After searching, I found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732300/caching-product-display-with-display-cache-and-still-be-able-to-add-products but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you checked the products in cart? does the number of item for that product incremented?